# MySQL: Can't find record in tablename

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, corruption

After crash:

```
mysql> repair table lot_not_sold;
+------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                  | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                      |
+------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | info     | Found block with too small length at 126188; Skipped          |
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | info     | Wrong block with wrong total length starting at 147688        |
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | info     | Wrong bytesec:   4-253-223 at 9784004; Skipped                |
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | info     | Wrong bytesec:  48- 32-208 at 11538216; Skipped               |
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | info     | Delete link points outside datafile at 4036632                |
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | info     | Wrong bytesec:   0-  0-  0 at 1405636; Skipped                |
.... rows were skipped a lot ....
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | warning  | Number of rows changed from 113619 to 115277                  |
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | repair | status   | OK                                                            |
+------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
616 rows in set (1.77 sec)
```

More output [here](http://pastie.org/5634146), however I had to skip a lot of lines too due to size limit.

```
SELECT * FROM coinprice.lot_not_sold  ORDER BY site DESC limit 2;
+------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+------------+------+
| id         | fulltitle                  | added               | finish | site | startprice | blitzprice | url  |
+------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+------------+------+
| 2924913561 | tttt 10 tttttttt 2001 ttttt| ▒338-14-08 91:97:60 | NULL   |   78 |      0.000 |      4.379 | NULL |
| 2926483072 | Zamek w Krniku - 2z - 1998 | 2013-01-06 06:40:01 | NULL   |    5 |      2.839 |      0.000 | NULL |
+------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------+------+------------+------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note `added` is obviously incorrect for the first row.

```
mysql> delete from lot_not_sold where site>5;
ERROR 1032 (HY000): Can't find record in 'lot_not_sold'
```

Try to check:

```
mysql> check table lot_not_sold extended;
+------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table                  | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| coinprice.lot_not_sold | check | status   | OK       |
+------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (2.95 sec)
```

Next try to select again, delete, repair - and always have the same result.

```
mysql> show create table lot_not_sold;

 CREATE TABLE `lot_not_sold` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fulltitle` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `finish` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'дата закрытия торгов',
  `site` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `startprice` float(8,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `blitzprice` float(8,3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`site`,`added`),
  KEY `IX_lot_not_sold_added` (`added`),
  KEY `IX_lot_not_sold_finish` (`finish`),
  KEY `IX_lot_not_sold_site` (`site`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=114
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (DAY(added))
PARTITIONS 4 */
```

Is it possible to fix this error? Is is possible there are way many errors because `repair` added ~2k rows?

I googled sone pages mentioned very old bug but my instance is not too old:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

MyISAM was choosen because of performance reason. Now I'm considering switching to InnoDB - is it the right way? This table constantly modified.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use the `REPAIR TABLE myTable USE_FRM`

"Probably" your `.MYI` file is missing or have corrupted headers

> This option tells MySQL not to trust the information in the .MYI file
>   header and to re-create it using information from the .frm file

However before proceed check the documentation of your [MySQL 5.1 version](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) **and make a backup copy of your `.MYI`,`.frm`, and `.MYD` file in order to avoid loss of data**